SwiftUI Menu element tappable area
When I tap on upper green area(white dot location), "onTapGesture" tap is registered and vibration occurs, but menu doesn't open, is it how its supposed to work or am I missing something? Menu(red background) is inside HStack(green background)
Menu {
    ForEach(self.array, id: \.self) { element in
        Button(element[1] + ":" + " " + element[0] , action: {
            self.selectedCurrency = element[0]
            self.selectTrigger.toggle()
        })
    }
} label: {
    Text(selectedCurrency)
    Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
}
.background(.red)
.fontWeight(.bold)
.foregroundStyle(.customSecondary)
.sensoryFeedback(.selection, trigger: selectTrigger)
.onTapGesture {
    print("Tapped")
    isFocused = false
    self.selectTrigger.toggle()
}




Since every time when you apply view modifier to any view, a new view is returned, so you have applied your onTapGesture not on Menu actually.
You can check this by increasing frame of background and then apply your tapGesture, you'll see that onTapGesture will work only on the increased area.
Speaking of the applying onTapGesture to a button or a menu. Since both of these views have their own tappable area, they won't respond to onTapGesture applied to their initial tappable area.
But if you add a frame that is bigger than their initial tappable area, your tapGesture will work, but initial action will not, since it is a new view that is not related to button's/menu's primary action and to initiate it you have to tap on the initial tappable area.
To increase your tappable area of Menu, you need to create custom MenuStyle.
Overriding Menu's primary action:
Menu has a few initializers that allows to override its primary action. So you can put any logic inside this block. It has one drawback you need to know about, primary action will no longer present menu items. To present them user will have to long press on the menu view.

Thanks for your reply, i've tried to add .frame before .background and add onTapGesture after that, it increases tappable area, but Menu tap also works as before, it works on whole background area, including Menu, but if i try to make background frame smaller than Menu frame, it still recognizes taps outside of Menu.
GIF Link

@user24018863 what exactly you’re trying to achieve?

To do some action (change focusState and trigger vibration) when menu is tapped and opened, couldn’t find better option to track menu opening state.
